# Php home page redirect blank

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, mysql

I have an issue with this code. when I login it takes it does not take me to the home page but stay on the login page. I want to redirect users to (http://localhost/trial/index.php#Home) When successfully logged in. How to fix that?

```
<!-- Including header file which contains j query and other libraries -->
<?php include("inc/incfiles/header.inc.php"); ?>
<?php
//Check if user is logged in or not
if (!isset($_SESSION["user_login"])) {
//Verification
}
else
{
 //Do nothing
}
?>

<?php
//Login Script
//user Login code
//Check user info when user inputs login information
if (isset($_POST['user_login']) && isset($_POST['password_login']) )
{
//filters input info
$user_login = preg_replace('#[^A-Za-z0-9)]#i','', $_POST['user_login']);//filters everything but numbers and letters
$password_login = preg_replace('#[^A-Za-z0-9)]#i','', $_POST['password_login']);//filters everything but numbers and letters
$password_login_md5 = md5($password_login); // encrypt password input because password in database is already encrypted in md5
//use Binary for case sensitive option
$sql = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT * FROM users WHERE BINARY username= BINARY'$user_login' AND password='$password_login_md5' AND closed='no' LIMIT 1"); //query
//check for existence if user exists
$userCount = mysqli_num_rows($sql); //Count the number of rows returned
//if username exists start session
if($userCount==1)
{
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($sql)) //fecthing the row to display information
{
$id = $row["id"]; // store user id into variable called $id
}
$_SESSION["id"] = $id;  
$_SESSION['user_login'] = $user_login;
$_SESSION["password_login"] = $password_login;
echo "succes!";
header("Location:#Home");
//exit("<meta http-equiv=\"refresh\" content=\"0\">");              
}
else{echo"That information is incorrect, Please try again!";}
exit(); 
}
?>  

<!-- The welcome page where users must provide login info in order to be logged in -->
<div data-role="page" id="Welcome">
<div role="main" id="loginform">        
React now
<form action="" method="POST"> <!--provide username and password then submit -->
<input name="user_login" size= "25" type="text"><br /><br /><!-- Enter username /include username placeholder later-->
<input data-clear-btn="false" name="password_login" size= "25" type="password"><br /><br /><!-- Enter password /include password placeholder later-->
<input name="login" value="Login" type="submit" data-theme="a"/><!-- submit button style it later -->
</form>
<div>
<a href="#Sign Up" data-role="button">Sign Up</a> <!--Redirect user to sign up page if user not member yet-->
</div>  
</div>
<div data-role="footer" data-position="fixed" data-theme="a"><!-- Footer display/ displays once-->
<h4>(C) 2016</h4> <!-- copyright symbols include later-->
</div>
</div>  <!-- End of the login page-->       

<!-- Sign up page where to allow users to sign up-->
<div data-role="page" id="Sign Up">
<div data-role="header" data-theme="a">
<h1>Sign Up</h1>
</div><br><br><br><br>
Sign Up for Reactr
<form>
<!-- Just left the form blank for the moment to make the code smaller and easy to read-->
</form>
<div role="main" class="ui-content">
</div>
</div><!-- End of the sign up page-->


<!-- HOME PAGE AND USER PROFILE PAGE where users can enter and submit texts-->
<div data-role="page" id="Home">
<div data-role="header" data-theme="a"><!-- Jquery settings ref included in the header file-->
<h1>Text</h1>
</div>
<!-- Allow users to search for posted texts-->
<div class="search_box">
<!-- Setting form to allow users to type text, send and search for texts-->
<form action="search.php" method="GET" id="search"><!-- Search form -->
<input type="text" name="q" size="60"/><!-- Search for text /include search placeholder later-->
</form>
</div>
<div role="main" class="ui-content">
Enter your Text<br><!-- Enter and send text -->
<input name="text-basic" id="text-basic" value="" type="text">
<a href="" data-role= "button" data-theme="a" onClick="submittext(Q)">Send</a><!-- submit button with onclcick function -->
</div>
</div><!-- End of the Home page-->
</body><!-- End code-->
</html>
```

Comment: Per [this posting](http://php.about.com/od/learnphp/ht/phpredirection.htm), `header("Location/index.php#Home");` will only work if it is placed ABOVE the `<html>` tag. You placed `<?php include("inc/incfiles/header.inc.php"); ?>` at the top of your file. That won't work.  Place that stuff AFTER you php test for valid login.

Answer (score 1):

You have at least two problems:

1 - Most importantly, you are attempting to redirect after sending some content with PHP, which is not allowed:

```
echo "succes!";
header("Location:#Home");
```

Remove the `echo` line to fix this.

2 - You also need to update your redirect to redirect somewhere server-side. PHP doesn't know about client-side directives, such as named anchors on a page (in your case `#Home`)

```
header("Location:#Home");
```

Update this to `header("Location:index.php#Home");` to resolve it. Note that if your index.php IS your home page, you may not need the `#Home` at all.

Answer (score 0):

The # symbol in your redirect causes the issue of staying on the same page - since this indicates that its an anchor location in the page you are already in. you need to change it to:

```
header("Location: index.php#Home");
```

also - if you are simply trying to redirect your user to the top of the home page - you don't need it at all - you would only try to take them to an anchor that exists further down the page. If what you are trying to direct them to is at the top of hte page just use the relative path with no anchor listed:

```
header("Location: index.php");
```

Comment: I removed the echo and did as you suggested but it is still not working. I'm building an app and I put all my pages in the index.php now what I want to do is to allow the user to go the home page which is also in the index.php if they are logged in successfully